# Powershell - .Net Arrays - Cannot index into a null array

Tags: .net, arrays, powershell

Been learning a bit of powershell and i have a problem, I've been trying to learn how to do arrays and found there are many ways i can do this. Some arrays are CPU/Memory inefficent and others arn't (So says the Internet).I beleive that what i am doing is referenceing .Net arrays but have not been able to quite make sence of it.

This has been my source of learning: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html

My Two questions are:
Is there a better way? (so im not wasteing my time)
And have i got my syntax correct?

Error:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Test\custadmin.ps1:54 char:34
+ out-file -filePath $log[0]::$log[ <<<< 1] -encoding 'UTF8' -append -width 200 -inputObject $log[3]
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Code:

```
#Variables
$date = Get-Date
$dateformat = $date.Year+$date.Month+$date.Day
$site = "Example"
$email = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$log = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$schedule = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$error = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

#Array Log Variables

$log.Add("\\$site-srv-sbs\Logs\") > $null #path
$log.Add("$dateformat_"+$env:UserName+".txt") > $null #name
$log.Add("This is a report /n/r --------------------- /n/r/n/r Username: "+$env:UserName+" /n/rComputerName: "+$env:computername+" /n/r/n/r") > $null #body

#Log txt file
out-file -filePath $log[0]::$log[1] -encoding 'UTF8' -append -width 200 -inputObject $log[3]
```

Comment: What's with the `$log[0]::$log[1]` notation? Do you expect the string `"\\Example-srv-sbs\Logs\"` to expose a method named `2017612Werezwolf.txt`?

Comment: You're trying to optimize this in ways you probably shouldn't be - even if this does have a noticeable impact on running time (not likely) it's at the cost of readability, if you're trying to squeeze seconds off a scripted language you may as well just switch to a compiled language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Burt_Harris' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491322/45375) contains good general advice regarding arrays and the semantics of your array use.

It is worth repeating Burt's advice at this point: Using an *array*  for *your particular use case* seems misguided; individual variables make for a more readable and maintainable solution.

The rest of this answer leaves this aspect aside (presumably, the specifics of your code are secondary and your question is about array use in general) and shows **how to use arrays and other syntax features in a PowerShell-idiomatic way.**

---

Unless performance is paramount - such as when gradually building up a large array - **using PowerShell's own arrays (which are of .NET type `[System.Object[]]`) is simpler** than dealing with `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`:

```
# * Since all elements are known in advance, simply use `,`, the array-constructor
#   operator to create your array.
# * Also note that I've embedded the variable references directly
#   inside "...", with variable names disambiguated with {...}, where necessary.
# * Finally, /n/r instances have been replaced with `r`n (CRLF) - note that ` (backtick)
#   is the escape char. in PowerShell.
$log = "\\$site-srv-sbs\Logs\",
       "${dateformat}_${env:UserName}.txt",
       "This is a report`r`n---------------------`r`n`r`nUsername: $env:UserName`r`nComputerName: $env:computername`r`n`r`n"
```

**If efficiency matters:**

- For efficiently *extending* an array *iteratively*, use `$arrayList =
  [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()` or its generic, strongly-typed cousin; e.g., with `[string]` instances, `$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()`.
  While PowerShell conveniently allows you to "extend" an array with `+=`, an entirely new array must be allocated behind the scenes every time.
- For efficiently *storing* an array (which rarely matters in a shell environment, however) and/or *type-safe access*, use `$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]::new()`, for instance, but note that storage efficiency is only improved for *value* types (such as `[int]`), not *reference* types (such as `[string]`).
  Another beneficial side effect with value types is *slightly faster element access*.

---

It looks like your intent with `$log[0]::$log[1]` was to simply ***concatenate* `$log[0]` and `$log[1]`**, in which case you have several options - note that `$log[2]` rather than `$log[3]` must be used with `-InputObject`, because, as Burt points out, `2` is the last element's index, not `3`:

```
# Use "..."
# Inside "...", anything beyond a simple variable access - such as indexed
# access here - must be enclosed in $(...), the subexpression operator.
Out-File -FilePath "$($log[0])$($log[1])" -encoding UTF8 -append -width 200 -inputObject $log[2]

# Alternative, using an expression:
Out-File -FilePath ($log[0] + $log[1]) -encoding UTF8 -append -width 200 -inputObject $log[2]

# Generally preferable: Using the Join-Path cmdlet
Out-File -FilePath (Join-Path $log[0] $log[1]) -encoding UTF8 -append -width 200 -inputObject $log[2]
```

---

The **reason for your syntax error**:

`::` is the static dereferencing operator, whose purpose is to provide access to a .NET type's static members (properties and methods) - see [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators).

`$log[0]` is of type `[string]`, so `::` looks for static members of that type.

Because `::` has higher precedence than `[]` - see [`Get-Help about_Operator_Precedence`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Operator_Precedence) - `$log[0]::$log` is evaluated first, which looks for a static member whose name is the value of `$log`.

Because a member name is a *string* and `$log` is an *array*, `$log` is coerced to a string, which in PowerShell is a space-separated list of the array's elements.

Clearly, no such static member exists on type `[string]`, so that part of the expression evaluates to `$null`.

`[0]` is then applied to `$null`, which is invalid, and results in the error your saw (`Cannot index into a null array.`).

Comment: Thanks for catching the `[3]` issue - hadn't even noticed - answer updated. I agree that an array is a poor choice in this use case - which is why I linked to your answer (mentioning the "semantics of the array use"), but I've added a more explicit recommendation since. That said, my answer is based on the assumption that the OP is struggling with various _syntax_ aspects of PowerShell, and that the specific use case was secondary.

Comment: @Burt_Harris: I've restructured the answer to get the don't-use-an-array-for-this warning out of the way first. So, with the understanding that arrays make no sense for the (possibly contrived) specific use case in the question established, the rest of the answer hopefully provides useful general guidance.

Comment: The syntax is definitely something I’m struggling with for powershell, I am rather used to PHP. Reason for doing all the variable in an array was that it brought everything into a clear manner for me to learn more and keep track of them, as you could see I just appended comments on where the arrays variables linked to.  I had spent a few hours trying multiple ways to make the script work but never could find detail into errors that I had been trying to resolve. Thank you and @Burt_Harris for helping me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a better way.   PowerShell uses .Net arrays behind the scenes *all the time,* so you really don't need to be explicitly using ArrayLists etc.

If you need an array in PowerShell you can create them in a number of ways.   In PowerShell, its so natural that its almost hidden from you.  For example:

```
 $array = 1,2,3
```

or

```
 $files = get-childitem *.log
```

Both really create arrays.  Don't start out trying to find an application for arrays, by trying to fit all your variables into $log, that's unnatural.   Create variables with meaningful names rather than having to remember that $log[3] hasn't had any data stored in it yet.

Comment: That's good advice on both counts, but note that the reason for the error is solely `$log[0]::$log[1]`, not any missing array elements. (As an aside: `Out-File` wouldn't complain about `$null` being passed to `-InputObject` - it would just write an empty file (except for a BOM)).

Comment: @mklement0, thanks you are right that `$log[3]` isn't generating the error, but it's a great example of how using named variable is better than array elements.  You can make such mistakes visible by enabling **`Set-StrictMode -Version latest`**.